# darkbowser.canonical.com downloads lot of data in background

Tags: 20.04, canonical

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and while working I saw that a lot of data was being consumed by my machine in the background. I ran `iftop` on my terminal and saw that a lot of data was being consumed by `darkbowser.canonical.com`.

[image]

I've never come across this name and I couldn't find anything useful in my google search. Does anybody know what is this process and why was it consuming so much data in the background?

Comment: Use `sudo ss -lpn` to discover exactly which process is communicating. That will provide vital clues. Canonical servers provide many different services.

Comment: It is usually indeed snapd when performing updates (updates in snaps are not initiated by the user)

Answer (score 1):

For me it is snapd.

# **netstat -apt|grep darkbrowser**

tcp        0      0 rwks:41344              darkbowser.canoni:https ESTABLISHED 47555/snapd