darkbowser.canonical.com downloads lot of datas in background
I'm running Ubuntu 23.04 and while working I saw that a lot of data was being consumed by my machine in the background. I ran iftop on my terminal and saw that a lot of data was being consumed by darkbowser.canonical.com.
image
I've never come across this name and I couldn't find anything useful in my google search. How can I find out about this process and stop it?

your google search skills are lacking https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263388/darkbowser-canonical-com-downloads-lot-of-data-in-background  ;)  it is "snapd".

I looked into this question, but I couldn't find it on snapd
